# Solving $\left(1+3+5...+(2n+1)\right ) + \left(3.5+5+6.5+...+(\frac{7+3n}{2})\right)=105$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions, telescopic-series

$\left(1+3+5...+(2n+1)\right ) + \left(3.5+5+6.5+...+(\frac{7+3n}{2})\right)=105$

It is the equation that I did not understand how to find $n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $$(n+1)^2+\frac{(2\cdot3.5+n\cdot1.5)(n+1)}{2}=105$$
I got $n=6$.

I used the following formula.

$$S_n=\frac{(2a_1+(n-1)d)n}{2}.$$
Thus,
$$1+3+...+(2n+1)=\frac{(2\cdot1+n\cdot2)(n+1)}{2}=(n+1)^2.$$
Also, we can use the following nice reasoning.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(k^2-(k-1)^2)=(n+1)^2.$$

Comment: how did you get $(n + 1)^2?$

Comment: @Sarvar I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$1+3+5+...+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$
and $$3.5+5+...+\frac{7+3n}{2}=\frac{1}{4}(3n+14)(n+1)$$

Comment: how did you get  $(n + 1)^2?$

Comment: $$1=1^2,1+3=4=2^2,1+3+5=9=3^2$$ and so on

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^n k =\tfrac12 n(n+1)$
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n(2k+1) + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{7+3k}{2}
&= \left(2\sum_{k=0}^n k + (n+1)\right) + \left(\frac72 (n+1) + \frac32\sum_{k=0}^nk\right)\\
&= \left(n(n+1) + (n+1)\right) + \left(\frac72 (n+1) + \frac34 n(n+1)\right)\\
&= (n+1)^2 + \frac14 (3n+14)(n+1)\\
&=\frac14 (n+1)(7n+18)\\
&= \frac{7n^2+25n+18}{4}
\end{align}
Then solve the quadratic equation $\frac{7n^2+25n+18}{4} = 105$:
$$7n^2+25n+18 = 420 \implies 7n^2+25n-402 = 0$$

which has roots at $n=-\frac{67}{7}$ and $6$. Clearly $n$ must be positive, so $n=6$.

Comment: To whomever downvoted, may I ask why? This was a more thorough and elementary answer than the others provided and was answered at the same time

Comment: If you check the various profiles, you'll see that someone came through and systematically downvoted the question and all the answers -- the downvotes all came within a few seconds of one another (except for the one on my answer, which was posted later -- it may have been the same downvoter coming back). My guess is they thought the problem was not well asked and shouldn't have been answered. I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

If you double both sides and pair up terms from the two sums you're looking at the equation

$$210=(2+7)+(6+10)+(10+13)+(14+16)+\cdots+((4n+2)+(7+3n))\\=9+16+23+30+37+44+\cdots+(7n+9)$$

so you can just track the running sum until you get to $210$, i.e.,

$$9+16=25, 25+23=48, 48+30=78, 78+37=115, 115+44=159, 159+51=210$$

This tells you to stop at $51=7\cdot6+9$, so the solution is $n=6$.

Remarks:  What makes this work is that $210$ is small enough that it only takes a few additions to get the answer.  If the problem had, say a six-digit number on the right hand side instead of $105$, you'd be better off using the summation-formulae approach of the other answers.  Note also that the number $105$ was chosen so that there actually is a solution; if you had some random integer, the summation-formulae approach would give an answer for $n$, but it wouldn't be an integer.